# No methods matching the name(s) stream in hierarchy of class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

Tags: java, mockito, java-stream, powermock, powermockito

So I am using java 8 and trying to write some tests with PowerMock and Mockito. I am getting a `MethodNotFoundException` with the message:

`No methods matching the name(s) stream were found in the class hierarchy of class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.`

I double checked the [ArrayList documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)  and it definitely looks like it inherits `stream` from Collections. Is this a problem with PowerMockito or am I missing something?

Line in question

```
PowerMockito.when(thing.call("services", "things")).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("testService")); // Doesn't matter if it's new ArrayList<String>()));
```

Then has something like this called on it

```
services.stream().filter( x -> //filter).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

**EDIT:** After further research this appears to be a PowerMock Problem. Would love a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appeared to be a bug in PowerMock 1.5.5 and has been solved in 1.5.6

Reference: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/536

Comment: Issue is there even with 1.5.4

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is an inner class of `java.util.Arrays` returned by `Arrays.asList()`, and is not the same as `java.util.ArrayList`.

If the `stream()` method can't be found, it might be because `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is private?

Comment: This is a fair point. But I have now tried it with just a new ArrayList<String>() and the error still shows up.

Comment: Found the problem. Bug in powermock Thanks for your help