# How to Mock DataSource Dependency Injection Despite Being Accessible via Static Method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, integration-testing, powermock

I'm using [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/), [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) and [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) to unit test my database code. I'm also writing integration tests of course.

I'm having trouble understanding how to inject a mocked [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) into the system under test (class I'm testing). The `DataSource` is used for connection pooling, and therefore other classes can call a `static` method in the same class in order to retrieve an instance of this `DataSource`. This means that the `DataSource` is not injected into any constructors, anywhere, and so my tests don't have any constructors to inject the mocked `DataSource` into.

I'm getting around this by altering the logic of my real code to check if a private variable is null, and if so then use the injected DataSource (bad design since it's only needed for tests), otherwise it calls the static method to retrieve the connection pool's source (better design).

How do I inject a mocked `DataSource` into a class that doesn't have a constructor set up to accept it, because it can instead just call the static method to retrieve the dependency?

**Class to Test**

```
public DBConnection(DBSource dbSource) {   // <--- Constructor only required for test purposes :(
        this.dbSource = dbSource;
    }

    public final void createCompsDB() {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            if(dbSource==null){ 
                conn = DBSource.getInstance().getConnection();
            }else{
                conn = dbSource.getConnection(); /** Likely bad design, since dbSource is only NOT null for tests, so that you can inject the mocked datasource :(  */
            }
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE placesdb");
            System.out.println("Database created...");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
              // ...
            }
        } finally {
            // Close Resources... 
        }
    }
 }
```

**Test Class -- Test Passes**

```
public class DBConnectionTest {
        final Statement statement = mock(Statement.class);
        final Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
        final DBSource dataSource = mock(DBSource.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException, IOException, PropertyVetoException {
        when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
        when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateCompDBIfNotAlready() throws Exception {
        DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection(localDB, dataSource); /** This constructor is only needed for testing :( . How do I avoid it since all the classes I need to test don't require the dependency to be injected? */
        dbConnection.createCompsDB();    
        verify(statement).executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE PLACES");
    }
}
```

**DBSource.java**

```
protected DBSource() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUsername("user");
        ds.setPassword("pass");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/placesdb");
    }

    public static DBSource getInstance() {   // <--- Static method means dependent classes don't need to accept injections
        if (datasource == null) {
            datasource = new DBSource();
            return datasource;
        } else {
            return datasource;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.ds.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocking of the static class methods may be done with PowerMockito.
The test class should be something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DBSource.class)
public class DBConnectionTest {
    @Mock
    final Statement statement;
    @Mock
    final Connection connection;
    @Mock
    final DBSource dbsource;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException, IOException, PropertyVetoException {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DBSource.class);
        when(DbSource.getInstance()).thenReturn(dbsource);
        when(dbsource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
        when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateCompDBIfNotAlready() throws Exception {
        DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection(localDB); // No test-only constructor anymore
        dbConnection.createCompsDB();    
        verify(statement).executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE PLACES");
    }
}
```

You can read [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/04/powermock-mockito-mocking-examples.html) more about mocking with PowerMock.

Comment: Thanks @asch, I'm confused why you'd  mock `DBSource.class` since it is not static, but it's `.getInstance()` method *is* static. If I use your suggested `when(DataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);` then it returns an error referencing `DataSource`, which I assume you meant `DBSource` which also returns an error.  I changed my `setUp()` method's first 2 lines to state: `PowerMockito.mockStatic(DBSource.class);
when(DBSource.getInstance().getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);` but this causes a NullPointerException, saying `DBSource` is null (?). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Basically: I'm getting a NullPointerException with `when(DBSource.getInstance().getConnection()).thenReturn(conn‌​ection);` because we're mocking `DBSource.class` despite the fact it isn't static at all, but it's `.getInstance()` method is. Your thoughts? Thanks

Comment: So getInstance should be mocked as well. I have updated the solution.

Comment: Your code causes this error: `org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No methods matching the name(s) createStatement were found in the class hierarchy of class java.lang.Object` .... which is caused by this line: `when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);`. Are you able to get the code to work? I'm wondering if this is [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33370482/3851150), despite being supposedly fixed.

Comment: @Nova, I explained the general idea of mocking with PowerMock for mocking static methods. So now you can avoid adding of just-for-test constructor. I cannot cause your code work - it is your challenge. I am using PowerMock a lot - it is working as a charm. Try to follow all the instructions in the post I suggested. Looks again over your code. The bug you mentioned is not related.

Comment: Actually, it *is* caused by a bug. Confirmed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40999548/3851150). I switched from version 1.6.6 to 1.6.5 and it's solved. Thanks for your time